# The HighCharts CSV export module went missing

Tags: php, csv, highcharts

I have been using HighCharts succesfully with this tweak http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvD/

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Download CSV',
    onclick: function () {
        Highcharts.post('http://www.highcharts.com/studies/csv-export/csv.php', {
            csv: this.getCSV()
        });
    }
});
```

but just today, I'm finding that the page at *highcharts.com/studies/csv-export/csv.php* seems to be blank, rending the Export To CSV option non-functional. Even this jFiddle page isn't working for me. Has the *csv.php* code moved? Can I get it and put it on my own server to regain that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The source code to that file is [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/studies/csv-export/csv.php).  It is crazy complicated :)